# How can I connecting NanoPool.org API to Telegram by Json

Tags: json, telegram

I'm using cryptocurrency mining website [NanoPool.org](https://nanopool.org)
I should check the Data of this site for example Hashrate, workers and other things like that
I want to know how can I connect this site to my telegram.
Actually I don't know nothing about that, the only thing I aware about is that, the site have API with json but I searched a lot on Google couldn't find accurate training about that.

This is [API](https://xmr.nanopool.org/api) link of this website.

Would you please help me how can I do that?

Thanks

User Data example code:

```html
{
    "account": "4AHBwkKjWT2jHv83V6ahZXUWCYe9JmyNygQJ7ueQUMhHJrJQJrWnYHHUMuaZhCGSnvKTjodddyxqwdz8y2o7aKRV6C1xntS",
    "unconfirmed_balance": "0.36812920",
    "balance": "5.87838746",
    "hashrate": "2767380.0",
    "avgHashrate": {
        "h1": "2777915.0",
        "h3": "2773365.0",
        "h6": "2726529.2",
        "h12": "2648470.4",
        "h24": "2764918.3"
    },
    "workers": [
        {
            "id": "is",
            "hashrate": "1861860.0",
            "lastShare": 1505534231,
            "rating": 322640212,
            "avg_h1": "1855980.0",
            "avg_h3": "1860296.7",
            "avg_h6": "1858237.5",
            "avg_h12": "1854944.6",
            "avg_h24": "1854664.6"
        },
        {
            "id": "china",
            "hashrate": "905520.0",
            "lastShare": 1505534231,
            "rating": 118148712,
            "avg_h1": "921935.0",
            "avg_h3": "913068.3",
            "avg_h6": "868291.7",
            "avg_h12": "793525.8",
            "avg_h24": "910253.8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you connect it to telegram? Using a bot? Sending a private message? please describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with use of python json, telepot and requests libs
1. Receive json file from nanopool api via requests lib
2. Parse it via json lib
3. Create bot via botfather
4. Send it via telepot library as message to yourself from created bot